# Alternate Proof of Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: complex-analysis

If we know that every non-constant degree $n$ polynomial $f \in \mathbb{C}$ has exactly $n$ zeros, then we can deduce that $f(X) = a\prod_{i=1}^n(X - \alpha_i)$: Letting $\alpha_i$ denote the $i$th zero, take $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ so that $f(\beta) = a\neq 0$. Then $\prod_{i=1}^n(\beta - \alpha_i) = b \neq 0$, and so $\prod_{i=1}^n(\beta - \alpha_i) - ba^{-1}f(\beta) = b - ba^{-1}a = 0$. As $\prod_{i=1}^n(\alpha_i - \alpha_j) - ba^{-1}f(\alpha_j) = 0$ for all $ 1 \leq j \leq n$, we obtain more than $n$ zeros for a degree at most $n$ polynomial, implying $f(X) = ab^{-1}\prod_{i=1}^n(X - \alpha_i)$.

The interesting aspect of the above result is the Euclidean algorithm was never used. But I do not know of a proof of The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra that proves the assumption of the proof and yet does not prove the above result directly through the Euclidean algorithm. You can somewhat approximate a use for this result in $\mathbb{R}$, as if you do find $n$ zeros for $f$ with deg$(f) = n$, by Descartes' Rule of Signs we know there are exactly $n$ zeros, and so you can do a lot of elementary work with low degree polynomials with this method. So I am curious about a direct method of counting zeros of a polynomial topologically or analytically without taking a detour through algebra.

Comment: I don't follow.  Does your first paragraph invoke the FTA in order to prove the FTA?

Comment: My first paragraph only assumes that there are exactly $n$ zeros, not that $f(X)$ is a product of its zeros. I am curious of a method of finding the number of zeros of a polynomial without using the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: But that is equivalent since $\mathbb{C}$ is a field:  every root $a$ gives a linear factor $x-a$ and vice versa.